# express-session middleware to check authentication

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

I have a question about the usage of sessions with `express-session`. I really don't understand how the sessions are secure. For example in the following official guide: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html they create a middleware to check if the user is authenticated:

```
// middleware to test if authenticated
function isAuthenticated (req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user) next()
  else next('route')
}
```

But I don't understand, why isn't this middleware checking that the session is in fact, inside the DB? An attacker could just modify the session cookie with random values and there would be still some value in the `user` field, even if it's a garbage value, no? So the function still would think this is an authenticated user.

Why is this not possible?

In my case, I am setting the `userId` in the session and then every time someone makes a request, I retrieve its `userId`, but I do not understand, what if someone modifies the cookie and gets a random `userId` value? My application will think this user is authenticated, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why isn't this middleware checking that the session is in fact, inside the DB?

This check, which you rightly expect to be done, is already done *before*, in the `express-session` middleware: This looks up the value of the session cookie in the session storage (which can be a database) and populates `req.session` accordingly. Since the value of the session cookie is unguessable, an attacker who puts in a random value, will make `req.session` undefined, and the `isAuthentication` check will fail, as it should.